# How to feed tensors of variable shapes to tf estimator

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow-estimator

I am interested in studying graphs in tensorflow. The number of nodes varies from graph to graph in my dataset. This is problematic because, in my observation, tensorflow does not easily allow me to input data with variable shapes.

More specifically, could anyone suggest an easy way to feed batches of 2d arrays to a `tf.Estimator.estimator` , when the shapes of arrays are different? I have been using `tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn` for a dataset with fixed sizes, but I now need a different approach.

Comment: Can you pad the batches to a fixed size?

Comment: @mikkola Yes that is probably the way to go. I would need to pad 0s and then reduce the size in a tensorflow graph, but thought that would be a bit inefficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ragged tensor has been introduced for this purpose.

https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/ragged_tensor